# Invalid conversion from void (*) (...) to void (*) (...) in OpenCL clCreateContext

Tags: c++, c, opencl

I'm taking my first steps into both C++ and OpenCL to perform parallel computing, but I'm running into a bug attempting to pass a listener function to clCreateContext. My program (not shown) is crashing without error, so I need to add a function to forward OpenCL errors to stdout/stderr. The clCreateContext function has an argument for a function pointer that can be set to forward error messages to stdout or stderr. I get a compile time error however using Codeblocks/MinGW:

```
invalid conversion from 'void (*)(const char*, const void*, size_t, void*)' to 
'void (*)(const char*, const void*, size_t, void*)'
```

I've replicated the problem in the code below:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <CL\cl.h>

void pfn_notify(const char *errinfo, const void *private_info, size_t cb, void *user_data)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "OpenCL Error (via pfn_notify): %s\n", errinfo);
}

int main()
{
    /*Get platform and device info*/
    cl_platform_id platform_id = NULL;
    cl_uint ret_num_platforms;
    cl_int ret = clGetPlatformIDs(1, &platform_id, &ret_num_platforms);
    cl_device_id device_id = NULL;
    cl_uint ret_num_devices;
    ret = clGetDeviceIDs(platform_id, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, 1, &device_id, &ret_num_devices);

    /*Create openCL context*/
    cl_context context = clCreateContext(NULL, 1, &device_id, &pfn_notify, NULL, &ret);

     /*Some line after this throws an error*/
}
```

I have seen code examples of using this exact method and pfn_notify that have worked, and am not sure why my program isn't even compiling. Thanks in advance, and let me know if there's anything else I can post to help.

Comment: My guess: the argument has a different calling convention. Is it meant to be an `extern "C"` function?

Comment: Agree with David: The calling convention of the notify function is `CL_CALLBACK`, which may be different from your calling convention, or it could simply be missing `extern "C"` - I'd try `extern "C"` first.

Comment: @dfarce Note that if you're using C++, cl.hpp is a very good OO wrapper around the OpenCL API.  It's included with many implementations or downloadable from http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/api/1.1/cl.hpp and eliminates this sort of issues.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to declare your function as

```
void CL_CALLBACK pfn_notify(.....
```

As the commentors point out; if this code is in a C++ file then it also needs to be:

```
extern "C" void CL_CALLBACK pfn_notify(.....
```

Comment: This did the trick. I am quite new to C and C++ so I presume that extern C is a result of the OpenCL being based off C, correct? Do you think you could briefly explain the purpose of CL_CALLBACK in this instance?

Comment: It specifies a *calling convention*, which is basically a specification of how the function arguments appear on the stack, which end has to pop the stack, which registers are used for function arguments and return value , and other such things.  If you look in `cl_platform.h` it is defined there.

Comment: `extern "C"` means that the function is identified using the C ABI. The ABI (amongst other things) includes the format that a function signature takes in the compiled object file. C code uses the C ABI, and the CL library expects to link against a function signature in the C ABI.  C++ has a different ABI because you can have overloaded functions, so the ABI has to be more complicated for C++. (This is also known as *name mangling*).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I guess I'm off to try to debug my main program now!

Comment: As a side note, if you used C++ OpenCL, you could have used C++ function pointers directly. In addition, if you are new to OpenCL you rather beging using C++ OpenCL for a C++ application.